# how to handle multipart request using http client

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, multipart

Following is my code to handle `Multipart` using `httpclient`

```
if(methodParams.getDataType().length()>0 && methodParams.getDataType().equals("org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile")){
                isMultipart = true; 
                MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity( HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE );
                // For usual String parameters
                entity.addPart( methodParams.getVariableDefined(), new StringBody("".toString() , "text/plain", Charset.forName( "UTF-8" )));
                postURL.setEntity( entity );
             }
```

but i get the following exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.james.mime4j.util.CharsetUtil.getCharset(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/nio/charset/Charset;
    at org.apache.http.entity.mime.MIME.<clinit>(MIME.java:51)
    at org.apache.http.entity.mime.HttpMultipart.<clinit>(HttpMultipart.java:85)
    at org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity.<init>(MultipartEntity.java:77)
    at org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity.<init>(MultipartEntity.java:96)
    at com.hexgen.tools.HexgenClassUtils.doPOST(HexgenClassUtils.java:151)
    at com.hexgen.reflection.HttpClientRequests.handleHTTPRequest(HttpClientRequests.java:74)
    at com.hexgen.reflection.HexgenWebAPITest.main(HexgenWebAPITest.java:115)
```

EDIT:

following are the dependency i use

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

how to solve this.

Comment: You are using incompatible versions of httpmime and apache-mime4j I supose.

Comment: Please have a look at my edit

Comment: Alright, so there are some reasons to use 4.0.1 instead of the newest version?

Comment: 4.2.5 should work just fine ;)

Comment: And you may also remove dependency on httpclient [since httpmime depends on it](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpmime/4.2.4).

Comment: It looks like that 4.2.5 is not there yet. 4.2.4 should be available though

Comment: `java.lang.InstantiationException: org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile` now i get this one after changing the version

Comment: It looks like [fix described here](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?101120-MultipartFile-trouble!) might help you.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29295/discussion-between-anto-and-lifus)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at [dependencies](http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpmime/4.0.1/) [one more time](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpmime/4.0.3), perhaps you've missed some jars.

You may also replace your old jars with [newer version of a httpclient along with httpmime](http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi). httpclient is no longer relying on james mime4j [since version 4.1](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpmime/4.1).

You may also end up managing your dependencies with [maven](http://maven.apache.org/). Just in case if you are not using it.

**Edit:**

You may add the following

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.james</groupId>
    <artifactId>apache-mime4j</artifactId>
    <version>0.6</version>
</dependency>
```